# Swift UIText View replaceCharacters Out of bounds

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I try to replace link to image and show on TextView

This my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(textView)
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        let input = "New iPhone \nhttp://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/apple-iphone-6s1.jpg \nTest Test Test"
        imageText(text: input)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func imageText(text:String) {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector?.matches(in: text, options: .reportCompletion, range:NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
        for match in matches! {
            if match.url?.absoluteString.suffix(3) == "jpg" {
                let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (match.url!))
                if data != nil{
                    let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                    textAttachment.image = image
                    let attributedStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
                    attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: (match.range), with: attributedStringWithImage)
                }
            }
        }
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

It works:

[App Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP3sP.jpg)

But if I add a second link, then it crashes.

```
let input = "New iPhone \nhttp://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/apple-iphone-6s1.jpg \nTest Test Test \nhttp://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/apple-iphone-6s1.jpg \nTest Test Test"
```

console

```
reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'
```

I find the crash point is this line

```
attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: (match.range), with: attributedStringWithImage)
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to do it backwards. Because if you change the first one, then the length of your string if smaller, because your changed a long link to a small text attachment. Forget about the image, let's say you replace each links with "Hello", you understand. Now, to fix it: `for match in matches!` => `for match in matches!.reversed()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer It work

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: you are mutating `attributedString` in this line

```
attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: (match.range), with: attributedStringWithImage)
```

So, in the following iteration of the `for` loop, the range that you are trying to replace doesn't exist anymore.